# accessibility for image inside an anchor link with role button: Clickable elements must be focusable and should have interactive semantics

Tags: javascript, events, accessibility, keyboard-events

I have the following markup:

```
<li class="remove-filter-key-list-item" data-id="{{this.id}}">
  <a
    href="#"
    class="remove-filter-key-button flx jst-cntr"
    role="button"
    tabindex=0
  >
    <img
      class="remove-filter-key-list-icon"
      src="{{this.icon}}"
      alt="{{this.statusText}} icon"
    />
    <span
      class="remove-filter-key-list-title"
    >{{this.statusText}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

which is triggering [this error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Understanding_WCAG/Keyboard) in the firefox accessibility inspector:

[image]

From what I can gather, the link needs an onclick listener, a keydown listener, a tab index, and a`prevent default` on both events. I've tried adding those, but the error persists. Firefox seems to be focused on the image inside the anchor link, not the link itself, which is the clickable thing.

I'm adding the listeners in a javascript file (I do not and can't add them inline in the html) as follows:

```
function addStatusFilterListener(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", onStatusFilterToggle);
  el.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keycode === 32) {
      //if spacebar
      onStatusFilterToggle(e);
    }
  });
}
```

This doesn't seem to work though - the spacebar scrolls the page, and my event is not triggered, and it seems the accessibility inspector is looking for events on the contained `img` tag. What's the proper way to structure this to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a lot of workarounds and fiddles the most straight forward solution is to wrap the image in a button rather than trying to make an anchor behave like a button.

This means that you don't have to worry about different handlers etc. as a `click` event handler on a button has all the behaviour built in!

In the following example I changed your code to use a `<button>` instead and added a `data-id` just to alert to which item is clicked.

You will see that you can use <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to activate the item as well as a mouse click!

```js
const removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-filter-key-button');

removeBtn.forEach((element)  => {
   element.addEventListener('click', onStatusFilterToggle);
});

function onStatusFilterToggle(e){
  let el = e.currentTarget;  
  let itemID = el.getAttribute('data-id');
  alert("you pressed item: " + itemID);
}
```

```css
button{
   border: 0px;
   background: transparent;
}
button:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
   opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<button class="remove-filter-key-button flx jst-cntr" data-id="1">
    <img
      class="remove-filter-key-list-icon"
      src="https://picsum.photos/100/100"
      alt="Some Alt Text icon"
    /><br>
    <span
      class="remove-filter-key-list-title"
    >Current Status</span>
  </button>
  <button class="remove-filter-key-button flx jst-cntr"  data-id="2">
    <img
      class="remove-filter-key-list-icon"
      src="https://picsum.photos/100/100"
      alt="Some Alt Text icon"
    /><br>
    <span
      class="remove-filter-key-list-title"
    >Current Status</span>
  </button>
```

Comment: Just a note on this solution - when I implemented this, the image inside the button was still flagged as needing to be focusable and have interactive semantics. I was able to suppress that error by giving the image (an icon) the `aria-hidden` attribute. Another solution (not easy here because I had both image and text inside the button), would be to just set the icon as the background image for the button.

Comment: You could achieve the same with setting the `alt` attribute to `""` (`alt=""`) as this effectively hides the image from assistive tech (which is probably correct if it is just an icon as you have the status text). However this is a false positive anyway as there is no need for the image to be focusable so I am not sure what is causing the checker to pick that up (you don't have a stray `click` handler on the image by any chance as that is the only thing I can think that would cause it to suggest this?).

Answer (score 1):

Here are what I could say about your code:

- tabindex=0 is unnecessary, as a link is focusable by default.
- keyboard handler is unnecessary, since pressing enter already triggers the link and/or the click handler. It may even be dangerous because you are making the interface unusual against what's expected by the user for a link or button.
- Adding tabindex=0 to the `<img/>`, the `<span>`, or anything inside the link is going to create troubles; nested focusable or clickable elements create confusion because they aren't well understood by users and the actual events triggered isn't well defined and/or hard to handle well.
- The image has an alt text, so accessibility speaking, you seem all good